# 'Owner' formatting incorrectly applied on deleted comments

Tags: bug, comments, design, deleted-comments

There is special formatting for user links in comments posted by the author of the question; it has a different background, to distinguish it from comments from other users. However, this background is also applied to ♦ moderators when they delete such comments:

[image]

I'd expect my user link to be formatted as in the second comment, without special 'owner' formatting.